# Returning value of Cell in a Table - C# - selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to loop over a table if Id column  has the idNumber  then find The result column and if that matches "Accept" return true
I am stuck here is my code 
The first row is the header and The column Id  has a value "D-19"  and column result should have "Accept " value

```
     public string  ResultsTable()
    {


        var tableElement = Browsers.getDriver.FindElement(By.Id("datatable"));
        var trElementList = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        var tdElementList = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        /// var thElementList = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("th"));

        var columnIndex = -1;
        var ColumnConter = 1;
        const string desiredColumnHeader = "Result";
        const string desiredValue = "Accept";


        const string manuScrptId = "D-19";

        for (int tr = 0; tr <= trElementList.Count; tr++)
        {
            var row = trElementList[tr];

            IList<IWebElement> allCellsInRow = row.FindElements((By.XPath("./*")));
            foreach (var cell in allCellsInRow)
            {
                if (cell.Text== desiredColumnHeader)
                {
                    columnIndex = ColumnConter;

                }

                if (cell.Text == desiredValue)
                {

                }

                ColumnConter++;

            }



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your table structure will stay unchanged from each use and will use column indices to access the correct columns versus querying the table headers to find them.  If I am wrong please let me know and I'll update my answer.

Most tables will have a tbody which does not include the header information and will just include the rows.  I am searching for that first and then finding the rows.

I then loop through these found rows until I come across one that has the desired manuscript id and then I will check the Result column for a match and return the boolean of its status.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public string ResultsTable()
     {    
          IWebElement tableElement = Browsers.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#datatable tbody"));
          ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> tableRows = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

          // These are assumed values and need to be updated by you
          int idColumnIndex = 0;
          int resultColumnIndex = 5;

          const string desiredValue = "Accept";
          const string manuScrptId = "D-19";

          foreach (var row in tableRows)
          {
              ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rowCells = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

              if (rowCells[idColumnIndex].Text.Equals(manuScrptId))
              {
                  if (rowCells[resultColumnIndex].Text.Equals(desiredValue))
                  {
                      return true.ToString();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      return false.ToString();
                  }
              }
          }

          return false.ToString();
        }
```

- Made changes to return string instead of bool.  If you don't want "false" returned when the desired value is not found, you can return null instead.

If there is no way around needing to obtain the column headers each time then this should work:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public string ResultsTable()
     {
          IWebDriver Browsers = new ChromeDriver();

          Dictionary<string, int> columnHeaders = new Dictionary<string, int>();
          IWebElement tableElement = Browsers.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#datatable"));
          ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> tableRows = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

          bool getColumnHeaders = true;
          const string desiredValue = "Accept";
          const string manuScrptId = "D-19";

          foreach (var row in tableRows)
          {
              if (getColumnHeaders)
              {
                  columnHeaders = GetHeaders(row);

                  getColumnHeaders = false;
              }
              else
              {
                  ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rowCells = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

                  if (rowCells[columnHeaders["Id"]].Text.Equals(manuScrptId))
                  {
                      if (rowCells[columnHeaders["Result"]].Text.Equals(desiredValue))
                      {
                          return true.ToString();
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          return null;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          return null;
        }

private Dictionary<string, int> GetHeaders(IWebElement headerRow)
     {
          Dictionary<string, int> columnHeaders = new Dictionary<string, int>();

          int counter = 0;

          ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rowCells = headerRow.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

          foreach(var cell in rowCells)
          {
              columnHeaders[cell.Text] = counter;

              counter += 1;
          }

          return columnHeaders;
      }
```

- Where you see

rowCells[columnHeaders["Id"]].Text.Equals(manuScrptId)
rowCells[columnHeaders["Result"]].Text.Equals(desiredValue)

You will need to make "Id" and "Result" match the actual column header text desired.

Comment: You mentioned the data is dynamic except the header.  Can we assume the header stays the same?  If we can then we can use the expected column to check for the id and result instead of searching through each to find the headers with each run.

Comment: I changed the return from return true or return false to return true.ToString() or false.ToString().  This will return the string of the bool.  If you need to change this to a different string then you just need to do return "Some String";

Comment: are you saying that it passes back "true" no matter what desiredValue you use?  What exactly happens?  Is there a way for you to add or send the html or a link to it?